# domain user with local admin rights on web server windows 2016 not able to manage IIS

Tags: windows

We have domain user who is given local admin rights (part of local admin group) added to Windows server 2016 running IIS web services.  User still not able to administer IIS and/or perform admin activities on this server.  Any reason why we are seeing this behavior?  are we missing anything? Appreciate your inputs

Comment: I would try turning off and turning on the server.

Comment: Thank you. let me try this and see

Comment: this apparently worked. I removed the user and re-added back.  thanks a bunch